# Functional style React Native component successfully calls Redux Action but Class style component doesn't

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a Functional style React Native component where I can happily call my Redux Action:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Text, View, StyleSheet, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
import MultiSlider from '@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider';
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import {updateNumPosInCode} from './redux/actions/gameplayAction';

const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;

export default function Settings() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const numPosInCode = useSelector(store => store.gameplay.numPosInCode);

  const handleNumPosInCodeUpdate = num => {
    console.log(`handleNumPosInCodeUpdate: ${num}`);
    dispatch(updateNumPosInCode(num));
  };

  return (
    <View style={[styles.container]}>
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Number of Positions in the Code</Text>
        <MultiSlider
          sliderLength={width - 40}
          values={[6]}
          optionsArray={[4, 5, 6]}
          snapped={true}
          onValuesChangeFinish={handleNumPosInCodeUpdate.bind(this)}
        />
        <Text style={styles.text}>{numPosInCode}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20,
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
  },
  text: {
    textAlignVertical: 'center',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

However when I try to call the **same** action from this Class style React Native component, nothing happens.  Can you spot my mistakes?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, Button} from 'react-native';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {updateNumPosInCode} from './redux/actions/gameplayAction';

class ColourBoard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      numPosInCode: 5,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={[
          styles.MainContainer,
          {
            top: this.state.top,
          },
        ]}>
        <Button
          onClick={this.props.updateNumPosInCode(4)}
          title="Test"
          color="#841584"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  numPosInCode: state.numPosInCode,
});

// Actions:
const mapDispatchToProps = () => ({
  updateNumPosInCode,
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  MainContainer: {
    left: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 1,
  },
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps())(ColourBoard);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Your `mapDispatchToProps` usage is wrong.

With `connect`, [there's two ways to use `mapDispatch`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#two-forms-of-mapdispatchtoprops):

- passing in an object full of action creators, in which case you get all the same functions as props but already wrapped up to dispatch actions when called
- passing in a function that gets `dispatch` as an argument, in which case it's up to *you* to do the wrapping

In this case, you're passing in the function form of `mapDispatch`... **but you are only returning the plain action creators as the props, and *not* wrapping them to make use of `dispatch`!

The simplest answer here is to change it to `const mapDispatch = {updateNumPosInCode}` and pass that instead.

The *better* answer is to switch this to be a function component and make use of the `useDispatch` hook instead.